# Can't install sun-java6-bin package on Ubuntu Hardy (8.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04

I just upgraded to Hardy from Dapper and can't install java for the life of me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk
[sudo] password for bobpete:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  sun-java6-jre
E: Package sun-java6-bin has no installation candidate
```

I've inspected `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `apt-get update` several times, but no luck:

```
# 
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 6.06 _Dapper Drake_ - Release amd64 (20060531)]/ dapper main restricted


# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 6.06 _Dapper Drake_ - Release amd64 (20060531)]/ dapper main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ dapper-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-security universe
```

---

Update:
@tux21b your suggestion results in the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk
[sudo] password for bobpete:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. The package is in "multiverse". I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package **sun-java6-bin** doesn't exist anymore, because the content of it is now in the **-jre** package. Just read the error message carefully:

```
However the following packages replace it:
  sun-java6-jre
E: Package sun-java6-bin has no installation candidate
```

Simply try without the **-bin** package:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I just saw that [the package is in the "multiverse" section](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/sun-java6-jre), so you must enable that before...

The line you have to add to your sources.list is:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse
```

Then you can do a `apt-get update` and retry to install the packages.

Answer (score 9):

Being a total noob my self. Let me put this down VERY EASY, because i also struggled with this.

To be able to install sun-java with the "apt-get" command, you need to add a line to a file called "sources.list". This line can be found in /etc/apt/sources.list.
You edit it by writing: nano ../etc/apt/sources.list

Than at the very end of (bottom) of that file, you copy/paste the line:
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse

Now press Ctrl + X to exit, and "y" for saving.

Now type the command: apt-get update 
And when that is done, you can successfully run the command: 
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Answer (score 0):

Try only..

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

That should install the jre and bin stuff as dependencies.

Comment: same results: `E: Package sun-java6-jdk has no installation candidate`